# How to use enhancers (pipes, guards, interceptors, etc) with Nestjs Standalone app

Tags: aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

The Nestjs module system is great, but I'm struggling to figure out how to take full advantage of it in a Serverless setting.

I like the approach of writing my domain logic in `*.service.ts` files, while using `*.controller.ts` files to take care of non-business related tasks such as validating an HTTP request body and converting to a DTO before invoking methods in a service.

I found the section on [Serverless](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/serverless#serverless) in the nestjs docs and determined that for my specific use-case, I need to use the "standalone application feature".

**I created a [sample nestjs app here](https://replit.com/@darksinge/Nest-Standalone-Serverless-MinimalExample#lambda-handler.js) to illustrate my problem.**

The sample app has a simple `add()` function to add two numbers. I use `class-validator` for validation on the `AddDto` class.

```js
// add.dto.ts
import { IsNumber } from 'class-validator'

export class AddDto {
    @IsNumber()
    public a: number;
        
    @IsNumber()
    public b: number;
}
```

And then, via some Nestjs magic, I am able to get built-in validation using the `AddDto` inside my controller by doing the following:

```js
// main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Use `ValidationPipe()` for auto-validation in controllers
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })
  )

  await app.listen(3000);
}


// app.controller.ts
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Post('add')
  add(@Body() dto: AddDto): number {
    // Request body gets auto validated and converted
    // to an instance of `AddDto`, sweet!
    return this.appService.add(dto.a, dto.b);
  }
}

// app.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  add(a: number, b: number): number {
      return a + b
  }
}
```

So far, so good. The problem now arises when using this in AWS with a Lambda function, namely:

- I want to re-use the business logic in `app.service.ts`
- I want to re-use built in validation that happens when making an HTTP request to the app, such as in the example above.
- I want to use the standalone app feature so I don't have to spin up an entire nest server in Lambda

The [docs hint](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/serverless#using-standalone-application-feature) on this being a problem:

> Be aware that NestFactory.createApplicationContext does not wrap controller methods with enhancers (guard, interceptors, etc.). For this, you must use the NestFactory.create method.

For example, I have a lambda that receives messages from AWS EventBridge. Here's a snippet from the sample app:

```js
// standalone-app.ts
interface IAddCommand {
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

export const handler = async (
  event: EventBridgeEvent<'AddCommand', IAddCommand>,
  context: any
) => {
  const appContext = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
  const appService = appContext.get(AppService);
  const { a, b } = event.detail;
  const sum = appService.add(a, b)
  // do work on `sum`, like cache the result, etc...
  return sum
};

// lambda-handler.js
const { handler } = require('./dist/standalone-app')

handler({
  detail: {
   a: "1", // is a string, should be a number
   b: "2" // is a string, should be a number
  }
})
  .then(console.log) // <--- prints out "12" ("1" + "2") instead of "3" (1 + 2)
```

I don't get "free" validation of the event's payload in `event.detail` like I do with `@Body() dto: AddDto` when making a HTTP POST request to `/add`. Preferentially, the code would throw a validation error in the above example. Instead, I get an answer of `"12"` -- a false positive.

---

Hopefully, this illustrates the crux of my problem. I still want to validate the payload of the event before calling `appService.add(a, b)`, but I don't want to write custom validation logic that already exists on the controller in `app.controller.ts`.

Ideas? Anyone else run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me while writing this behemoth of a question that I can simply use `class-validator` and `class-transformer` in my Lambda handler.

```js
import { validateOrReject } from 'class-validator'
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer'
import { AddDto } from 'src/dto/add.dto'

export const handler = async (event: any, context: any) => {
  const appContext = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
  const appService = appContext.get(AppService);

  const data = getPayloadFromEvent(event)

  // Convert raw data to a DTO
  const dto: AddDto = plainToClass(AddDto, data)

  // Validate it!
  await validateOrReject(dto)

  const sum = appService.add(dto.a, dto.b)
  // do work on `sum`...
}
```

It's not as "free" as using `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())`, but only involves a few extra lines of code.

Comment: or, I guess you could use `NestFactory.create` and `app.init` and then retrieve the underlying `express` instance, like they have done here: https://github.com/rdlabo-team/serverless-nestjs/blob/master/src/index.ts

Comment: That's a great suggestion! However, in order to keep the Lambda function as [lightweight as possible](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/serverless#using-standalone-application-feature), I explicitly do not want to spin up a nest server inside the Lambda function. The example you linked to also assumes the Lambda is the receiver of an HTTP request via the use of `aws-serverless-express`, which needs a handle on the underlying `express` app. I wanted a solution that integrates with [non-HTTP events in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with the following lambda file for nestjs.

```
import { configure as serverlessExpress } from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

let cachedServer;

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const nestApp = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    await nestApp.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
    await nestApp.init();
    cachedServer = serverlessExpress({
      app: nestApp.getHttpAdapter().getInstance(),
    });
  }

  return cachedServer(event, context);
};
```